# How to do async calls in koa

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, koa

I am using Koa 1.X. I fire a time-consuming call through visiting the api in the browser.
Key codes are as below:

```
const router = koaRouter();
router.get('/crawler', function*() {
  yield getZoneList();
  this.body = {
    state: 0
  }
});

function* getZoneList(){
  yield doSomethingAsync();
}
```

I do not want `getZoneList()` function to block the response to the browser. So I need `getZoneList()` to be executed asynchronously. How should I do?

Comment: Block the response to the *browser*? Are you sure that's what you want? Or do you want it not to block the *thread*?

Comment: Don't `yield` it if you don't want to wait for it? But what's the point of calling it when you're not interested in its result?

Comment: @Bergi, I have tried invoking `getZoneList`  without using `yield`. But `getZoneList` seems not to be executed. Debugging logs in `getZoneList` are not be printed. By the way, the browser is not interested in the result. It only triggers the call. The result would be saved to database directly.

Comment: Ah, right, `getZoneList` is a generator function not a promise-returning one so it still needs to be run. Best, use `co.wrap` around it, then it should work. Or call it like `co(getZonelist()).catch(e=>{/*ignore*/})`.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. That helps me.